# How often does a processor check if time on a timer is up to execute a program?

Tags: loops, timer, conditional-statements

For example, if we program a computer to check and update some variables every 5 minutes does that mean that the computer actually checks if the condition matches (if that 5 minutes are up so it can execute a program) every tick? So that means (in my point of view) the bigger the amount of conditionals or timers or both the heavier the load on the processor even though the processor just checks if the time is up or whether the condition is match or not.

My reasoning being here that the processor can't really put some task away and forget about it for 5 minutes and then just remember about it and execute the program. It has to keep a track of time (counting seconds or ticks or whatever), keep track of timers that are currently being on and check if the time on every timer is up or not.

That makes every timer a conditional statement. Right?

So the main question is... am I correct on all of those statements or the reality is a bit different and if so then how different?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi,welcome to SO. This is language, cpu and os related. Please read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that you have a basic understanding of how processes are managed in a CPU

Most programming languages implement some form of wait() function, that will cause the CPU to stop executing instructions from that thread until it is interrupted, allowing it to work on other tasks in the meantime. Waiting for an interrupt does not use much of the system's resources, and is much more efficient than the polling method that you were describing.

This is a pretty basic explanation, but if you want to learn more, lookup preemptive multitasking.

Comment: But isn't that while the processor is waiting it has to count how much time it has to wait and check if the time is up, so taking (not much i guess but still) system's resources?

Comment: I am not sure of the exact implementations myself, but it is using minimal resources